# Copy folder + subfolder + inner files access permissions and ownerships from one folder to an other (recursively)

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

How do I copy all the folder, subfolders and files permissions (recursively) from `/www_03062018` to my new `/www` ?

I came across this post: https://superuser.com/questions/625673/clone-permissions-for-all-files-in-a-folder

```
chmod --reference=RFile file
```

Which didn't help much, it did apply a change for the main folder `/www` but didn't apply on its subfolders and files.

i have tried:

```
chmod -R --reference=/www_03062018 /www
```

and it didn't work.

**My situation:**

I have 2 folders on my Ubuntu machine: `/www` and `/www_03062018`.

`/www` is a "git clone" from the production machine.

`/www_03062018` is my old directory that i used to work on and upload files via FTP.

I started to use GIT and when I clone a directory - all its folder ownerships and file accesses settings doesn't get cloned too.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the new directory which you want to give new permissions - in my case:

```
cd /www
```

For CHMOD this worked:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chmod --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'
```

And for CHOWN this worked:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chown --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'
```

Hope this helps others :) !